# How to pick unique pairs from a single list

Tags: java, list, sorting

I am creating a program which involves a segment of code where I am required to pick pairs out of a single list of items (names).

The initial list comes from a single `ArrayList<String>` which contains all the unique names of people.

My attempt is as follows:

```
//Performance is not really a focus as the lists are small (20 ~ 60 elements),
//thus I use a SecureRandom instead of a Random.
SecureRandom rnd = new SecureRandom();

//List of names
ArrayList<String> Names = new ArrayList<>();

//Names populated somewhere here..

//Make a secondary array which houses the available names...
ArrayList<String> AvailNames = new ArrayList<>();
AvailNames.addAll(Names);

LinkedHashMap<String, String> NamePair = new LinkedHashMap<>();
Iterator<String> Iter = Names.iterator();

// LOOP A
while(Iter.hasNext()){
    String name = Iter.next();
    int index;

   /*
    * LOOP B
    * Find a unique pair randomly, looping if the index is the same.
    * Not the most efficient way, but gets the job done...
    */
    while(true){
        index = rnd.nextInt(AvailNames.size());
        if(!AvailNames.get(index).equals(name)){
            break;
        }
    }

    NamePair.put(name, AvailNames.remove(index));
}
```

When the number of names is odd, I run into the problem where `LOOP B` (*See above*) run on indefinitely.

I've found out that the problem is with the fact that, sometimes, when all the pairs are taken, the last name-pair thats left is non-unique, causing the if-statement to never be true.

Take for example the list:

> 1. A
> 2. B
> 3. C
> 4. D
> 5. E

The program, during execution, may sort A to D first creating a name-pair such as the following:

> 1. A - B
> 2. B - C
> 3. C - D
> 4. D - C

Which leaves `E - E` as a final pair, which is not permitted as a pair (as the items/names are not **unique**). Since the pair-assignment is random, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't which is frankly quite annoying...

I'm sure the solution is very simple but for some reason I can't seem to find a way around this problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: That's an interesting problem. Maybe guarantee that it can't happen by dropping out of the loops when AvailNames.size is 2 and manually pair the last two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could detect when you get into this situation and just swap your last `AvailName` with the second element of some randomly chosen previous pair. For example if you picked the 2nd pair you would change it to B-E and your final pair would then be E-C.

This will always give two pairs each with different first and second elements: the chosen pair can't have E as its first element (you're about to generate the only pair which does) or as its second element (otherwise E wouldn't be in `AvailName`).

Comment: Hmm... That could work... but adds quite a bit of extra code. I was _hoping_ that something wrong with my code itself. If no one else points out some gaping mistake I made I will use your solution. Thanks for the input.

Comment: One alternative I can think of is to check at the penultimate step: if the last two names in `AvailNames` include the last name in `Names`, then pick it. That would mean instead of the last two pairs in your example you would generate D - E (force choice of the last) and E - C.

Comment: (Both solutions may well result in slightly non-uniform distribution across all possible valid arrangements, I'm afraid.)

Comment: Ehh... Was kinda hoping for uniform-distrbution... but again... this isn't some serious application so I guess it'll suffice. I guess I'll "pre-shuffle" the list to "randomize" it more... Gonna implement your solution, if it works (logically it does), I'll accept.

Answer (score 2):

Just a thought; you could compute *all* possible unique pairs and then sample randomly from that.

A note of caution is that this is O(n<sup>2</sup>) so could become slow for large numbers of names; and also the new `List` will get rather large as it contains n(n<sup>2</sup> -1)/2 elements.

Here is an example:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    final List<String> in = new ArrayList<String>() {
        {
            add("A");
            add("B");
            add("C");
            add("D");
            add("E");
        }
    };
    final List<String[]> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < in.size(); ++i) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < in.size(); ++j) {
            pairs.add(new String[]{in.get(i), in.get(j)});
        }
    }
    Collections.shuffle(pairs);
    for (final String[] pair : pairs) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pair));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[B, E]
[A, C]
[A, E]
[A, B]
[B, D]
[C, D]
[C, E]
[B, C]
[A, D]
[D, E]
```

You create a new `List<String[]> pairs` and then loop over the input `List`. In each iteration you loop over the remainder of the input - this guarantees that you never get the same pair again reversed.

Once you have populated `pairs` you simple `shuffle` it and take however many pairs you want. Given that `Random` samples from a uniform distribution you should end up with an equal probability of any ordering in `pairs`. You can also pass in your `SecureRandom` into the [other `shuffle` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Random%29).

Comment: I agree with you, it's basically the same solution i suggested.

Comment: One thing is that you don't find all the pairs, as mentioned in the question, eg: `C - D` and `D - C`.

Comment: You're possibly right - I assumed they were the same but judging by the question they are not.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like the following:

**Update:**

To counteract misunderstandings, the following piece of code will ensure:

- Unique Pairs
- In a random order

You will have `n!/(n-k)!` unique pairs, assuming there are no duplicate elements in the source list, where `n` is the number of names and `k` is `2` as we are creating pairs.

After creating the unique pairs, i shuffle them to get randomness.

To use a better shuffle algorithm, `Collections.shuffle(pairs, new SecureRandom())` could be used.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class NamePairTest {


  private static class NamePair {
    private final String one;
    private final String two;

    public NamePair(String one, String two) {
      super();
      this.one = one;
      this.two = two;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
      final int prime = 31;
      int result = 1;
      result = prime * result + ((one == null) ? 0 : one.hashCode());
      result = prime * result + ((two == null) ? 0 : two.hashCode());
      return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
      if (this == obj) return true;
      if (obj == null) return false;
      if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
      NamePair other = (NamePair) obj;
      if (one == null) {
        if (other.one != null) return false;
      } else if (!one.equals(other.one)) return false;
      if (two == null) {
        if (other.two != null) return false;
      } else if (!two.equals(other.two)) return false;
      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
      return one + " - " + two;
    }
  }


  public List<NamePair> createPairs(List<String> names) {
    List<NamePair> pairs = new ArrayList<>();
    // create all possible unique pairs, given the names list.
    for (String one : names) {
      for (String two : names) {
        // a pair must not have the same name twice
        if (!one.equals(two)) {
          NamePair newPair = new NamePair(one, two);
          // only add the pair if it is not already in the list of pairs.
          // this test will only be necessary if the names list contains duplicates.
          if (!pairs.contains(newPair)) pairs.add(newPair);
        } // if
      } // for
    } // for
    // now shuffle the list, as currently it is ordered.
    Collections.shuffle(pairs);
    return pairs;
  }


  public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> availableNames = Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D", "E");
    NamePairTest namePairTest = new NamePairTest();
    for (NamePair pair : namePairTest.createPairs(availableNames)) {
      System.out.println(pair);
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I want the actual pair-mappings to be unique, not the order of the pairs. Please excuse me if I read your code wrong but it seems like it defines the pairs in a predictable pattern and only randomizing the order of the pairs using `Collections.shuffle(pairs)` at the end.

Comment: That is correct, i create all possible pairs and then shuffle them. You could use ` Collections.shuffle(pairs, new SecureRandom());` if necessary. Maybe i miss the point somewhere? But you will get random pairs :)

Comment: I think your loop is somewhat inefficient. You loop over _all_ values and then test whether you have the same element on each iteration as well as looping over _all_ previous pairs in each iteration. This is `O(n^3)`. If you look at my answer you will see how to find unique pairs correctly.

Comment: You are right about the one thing in `!pairs.contains(newPair)`, but the comment stats that you don't have to do that, *if* there are no duplicates in the source list. As mentioned in the Question `A-B` and `B-A` is needed to be found. Look at `3. C - D` and `4. D -C` (in the original question).